# React Native Expo - "Rendered fewer hooks than expected" in ContextNavigator

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm facing an issue in my React Native Expo project where I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.

This error is located at:
    in ContextNavigator (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App) (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorToastContainer (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorOverlay
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

This error happens when I close/suspend (not quit) the Expo Go app and re-open it. I dont know how to troubleshoot this as the stack trace doesnt provide much information. I believe this issue is happening in the native IPA as well, as certain functionality breaks when closing the app, but I'm not certain.

I have searched the entire project (including node_modules) for "ContextNavigator" and "ExpoRoot". The only file mentioning these strings was `./node_modules/expo-router/src/ExpoRoot.tsx`. My package.json sets expo-router's version to `latest`.

This issue is being faced by all team members on every development machine and testing device (all iOS), so I don't believe it's a device-specific issue.

**What I've tried:**

- Tested on multiple iPhones (and iPhone simulators), they all face the issue.
- Issue is faced on both Windows & Mac.
- I have deleted node_modules and ran `yarn install`.
- I have deleted the `.expo` folder.
- I have tried running `npx expo start --clean`.

**Versions:**

```
$ npx react-native -v
11.3.6
$ npx expo --version
0.10.12
$ node --version
v18.17.0
```

We've been facing this issue for weeks with no luck. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @TheHerobrineKiller No luck